# How to export a 3D design and port it so it can be seen with Google CardBoard

Tags: 3d, google-cardboard, rajawali, virtual-reality, rajawalivr

I would like to know if its possible to use an existing 3D Design Software like Virtual Worlds or Sweet 3D Home to, say someone that refurbishes kitchens or create like a 3D space for a House or Room, and wants to see the design on the CardBoard. With a static position, not actually moving inside the virtual world.

What would be in a high level the steps to achieve this?

Is it possible using the Rajawali VR framework by somehow exporting the files from the Virtual Worlds software to the Rajawali Framework can read and show them?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving the Google Cardboard Unity SDK a shot. You might struggle to export the 3D space from your program, but you can certainly re-create it using the Unity SDK.

Also the VR Framework* probably handles allot of different functional aspects of Virtual Reality. The front end I.E the part that the user sees will be rendered by the SDK engine post compile time. So unfortunately, it's unlikely you'll be able to export your 3D environment.